# php and html output and display UTF-16 characters

Tags: php, character-encoding, utf-16

I am having some difficulty understanding how to output a UTF-16 string with PHP and having it properly displayed in the web page..

The string is from a game (it is a name) and can contain any of the characters.

I would like to output the given string "ムName" as `&#12512;Name` which would be interpreted by the browser as the original string ("ムName"). Thanks.

Comment: Where are you getting the string from?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$val="ムName";
echo mb_convert_encoding($val, 'HTML-ENTITIES','auto');
?>
```

demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/YFnx4a (view frame source to see the encoding)

Comment: But why would that be necessary in the first place? Would it not be much wiser to convert the string to UTF-8?

Comment: Thanks! This has worked on an initial test I am gonna get some stuff from the game and test it. Thanks again!